# winsound stops ongoing animation

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm newer to python, and very new to tkinter, and I need some help playing a sound every time a ball in the screen moves. This is the code I have

```
def leftMove(Event):
    canvas.move(circle_item2, -5, 0)
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)
    winsound.PlaySound('DoorSlam.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)

rightMove(Event):
 canvas.move(circle_item2, 5, 0)
 x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)

def upMove(Event):
 canvas.move(circle_item2, 0, -5)
 canvas.after(.1, upMove)

def downMove(Event):
 canvas.move(circle_item2, 0, 5)
 x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(circle_item)

root.bind('<Left>',leftMove)
root.bind('<Right>',rightMove)
root.bind('<Up>',upMove)
root.bind('<Down>',downMove)
```

The problem is every time I press the left key, it stops all animation until the sound is done playing. What is the proper way to make it so both play at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Play the sound in a separate thread, like this:

```
playSound = lambda: winsound.PlaySound('DoorSlam.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
t = threading.Thread(target = lambda: playSound)
t.start()
```